# Windows 10 drivers on MacBook Pro without bootcamp

Tags: windows-10, drivers, macbook-pro

I deleted all partitions from a MacBook Pro and installed Windows 8 on it from a disk, then upgraded to Windows 10.

However, after running Windows Update, it still lacks drivers for WiFi, audio, the touchpad, and a few other devices. I can't seem to find those drivers available for download from any official sources. And all the info I can find about it assumes that I left the BootCamp partition intact (which I did not).

To further complicate things, I do not know exactly which model of the MacBook Pro it is. I have found [this compatibility table](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204990#list), but not to much use.

How to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Open Apple Software Update for Windows and install available updates to get all the drivers. You will find additional details on the Mac models that support Windows 10 on the following [link](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204990). You can check your computer model by selecting the Apple menu and choosing About This Mac when you are booted into OS X.

Comment: I cannot boot into OSX for the reason that I deleted all partitions from the disk before installing Windows. I don't need OSX, I just want to run Windows on the thing.

Comment: You can try downloading the [boot camp support software](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1836?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) and installing it.

Comment: Hi Cam, did installing the support software work for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not :-( it does not find the correct drivers when I try to install devices manually from the boot camp folder.

Answer (score 0):

On my MacBook Pro (8,1 early 2011, MacOS 10.13) I first installed Win 7 via BootCamp and Win 7 install DVD. In Win 7 I installed the Win 7 drivers supplied by BootCamp. Then I downloaded MediaCretionTool from MS and with it I installed Win 10 over Win 7. After booting Win 10 Hardware Manager showed a few missing drivers. From https://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/apple/laptops-desktops/macbookpro8%2C1/1927 I downloaded and installed the following missing drivers:

- apple_broadcom_bluetooth_5040_win64
- apple_broadcom_cardreader_100243_win64 => BroadcomCardReader64.exe
- apple_cirrus_logic_hd_audio_win64 => CirrusAudioCS4206x64.exe
- FaceTime HD camera
- Intel_hd_graphics_win64_153332 => DisplayAudio
- intel_mei_10.0.27.1012 => PCI

After that I updated some of the drivers via Windows Update. Now everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you can boot into windows on the machine, you can use this to get the correct drivers: 
https://github.com/timsutton/brigadier

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.